# GCP SSL certificate in certificate Manager Fails Provisioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, gcp-load-balancer, gcp-certificate-manager

I tried creating a Public certificate in GCP for a custom domain have purchased in GCP. I want to use this certificate for Application LoadBalancers.

I added the Domain name and a wildcard (*.DN.com). It resulted in "FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE"

I then decided to create an SSL certificate for the domain name and subdomains instead of a wildcard but I still got the same error " FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE" and status "PROVISIONING".

Please what am I getting wrong? How do I create the certificate for the domain name and sub-domains for LoadBalancers?

Comment: The DNS for the domain is not configured correctly. Use Internet tools to test and validate your domain and its DNS configuration. Example: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/